# Elegant way to combine multiple collections of elements?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

Say I have an arbitrary number of collections, each containing objects of the same type (for example, `List<int> foo` and `List<int> bar`). If these collections were themselves in a collection (e.g., of type `List<List<int>>`, I could use `SelectMany` to combine them all into one collection.

However, if these collections are not already in the same collection, it's my impression that I'd have to write a method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Combine<T>(params ICollection<T>[] toCombine)
{
   return toCombine.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Which I'd then call like this:

```
var combined = Combine(foo, bar);
```

Is there a clean, elegant way to combine (any number of) collections without having to write a utility method like `Combine` above? It seems simple enough that there should be a way to do it in LINQ, but perhaps not.

Comment: Related: [listt-concatenation-for-x-amount-of-lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357722/listt-concatenation-for-x-amount-of-lists)

Comment: Beware of Concat for concatenating very large number of enumerables, could blow up your stack: http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/how-enumerableconcat-brought-down-a-production-server.html

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I think you might be looking for LINQ's [`.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
var combined = foo.Concat(bar).Concat(foobar).Concat(...);
```

Alternatively, `.Union()` will remove duplicate elements.

Comment: Thanks; the only reason I didn't do this in the first place is that (to me) it seems to get uglier the more collections you have to deal with. However this has the benefit of using existing LINQ functions, which future developers will likely already be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the `.Union()` tip. Bear in mind you **will need** to implement IComparer on your custom type in case it is.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0) Says you have to implement `IEquatable<T>` while in fact you only need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Answer (score 49):

To me `Concat` as an extension method is not very elegant in my code when I have multiple large sequences to concat. This is merely a codde indentation/formatting problem and something very personal.

Sure it looks good like this:

```
var list = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3);
```

Not so readable when it reads like:

```
var list = list1.Select(x = > x)
   .Concat(list2.Where(x => true)
   .Concat(list3.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Or when it looks like:

```
return Normalize(list1, a, b)
    .Concat(Normalize(list2, b, c))
       .Concat(Normalize(list3, c, d));
```

or whatever your preferred formatting is. Things get worse with more complex concats. The reason for my *sort of* cognitive dissonance with the above style is that the first sequence lie outside of the `Concat` method whereas the subsequent sequences lie inside. I rather prefer to call the static `Concat` method directly and not the extension style:

```
var list = Enumerable.Concat(list1.Select(x => x),
                             list2.Where(x => true));
```

For more number of concats of sequences I carry the same static method as in OP:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    return sequences.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

So I can write:

```
return EnumerableEx.Concat
(
    list1.Select(x = > x),
    list2.Where(x => true),
    list3.OrderBy(x => x)
);
```

Looks better. The extra, otherwise redundant, class name I have to write is not a problem for me considering my sequences look cleaner with the `Concat` call. It's less of a problem in **C# 6**. You can just write:

```
return Concat(list1.Select(x = > x),
              list2.Where(x => true),
              list3.OrderBy(x => x));
```

---

Wished we had list concatenation operators in C#, something like:

```
list1 @ list2 // F#
list1 ++ list2 // Scala
```

Much cleaner that way.

Comment: I appreciate your concern for coding style. This is much more elegant.

Comment: Perhaps a smaller version of your answer can be merged with the top answer here.

Comment: I like this formatting as well - although I prefer to perform the individual list operations (e.g. `Where`, `OrderBy`) first for clarity, especially if they're anything more complex than this example.

Comment: I like the static helper you showed, works great in my use case. Tweaked it slightly to allow null lists that might get passed into params:  ` return sequences.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x);`

Answer (score 36):

For the case when you *do* have a collection of collections, i.e. a `List<List<T>>`, `Enumerable.Aggregate` is a more elegant way to combine all lists into one:

```
var combined = lists.Aggregate((acc, list) => { return acc.Concat(list); });
```

Comment: How do you get the `lists` here first? That's the first problem OP has. If he had a `collection<collection>` to start with then `SelectMany` is just way simpler.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but this does seem to be answering the wrong question. Edited answer to reflect this. Many people do seem to end up here because the need to combine a List<List<T>>

Answer (score 14):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) like so:

```
var combined = foo.Concat(bar).Concat(baz)....;
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var query = foo.Concat(bar);
```

Answer (score 13):

You could always use Aggregate combined with Concat...

```
        var listOfLists = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4},
            new List<int> {5, 6, 7, 8},
            new List<int> {9, 10}
        };

        IEnumerable<int> combined = new List<int>();
        combined = listOfLists.Aggregate(combined, (current, list) => current.Concat(list)).ToList();
```

Comment: The best solution so far.

Comment: @Oleg `SelectMany` is just simpler.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I see is to use `Concat()`

```
 var foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
 var bar = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
 var tor = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 };

 var result = foo.Concat(bar).Concat(tor);
```

But you should decide what is better:

```
var result = Combine(foo, bar, tor);
```

or

```
var result = foo.Concat(bar).Concat(tor);
```

One point **why `Concat()` will be a better choice** is that it will be more obvious for another developer. More readable and simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Union as follows:

```
var combined=foo.Union(bar).Union(baz)...
```

This will remove identical elements, though, so if you have those, you might want to use `Concat`, instead.

Comment: No! `Enumerable.Union` is a set union which does not produce the desired result (it only yields duplicates once).

Comment: Yeah, I need the specific instances of the objects, as I need to do some special processing on them. Using `int` in my example might have thrown people off a little bit; but `Union` won't work for me in this case.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this, for any `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists` :

```
var combined = lists.Aggregate((l1, l2) => l1.Concat(l2));
```

This will combine all the items in `lists` into one `IEnumerable<T>` (with duplicates). Use `Union` instead of `Concat` to remove duplicates, as noted in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

A couple techniques using Collection Initializers --

assuming these lists:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
```

`SelectMany` with an array initializer (not really that elegant to me, but doesn't rely on any helper function):

```
var combined = new []{ list1, list2 }.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Define a list extension for Add which allows `IEnumerable<T>` in the `List<T>` [initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items) collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then you can create a new list containing the elements of the others like this (it also allows single items to be mixed in).

```
var combined = new List<int> { list1, list2, 7, 8 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're starting with a bunch of separate collections, I think your solution is rather elegant.  You're going to have to do *something* to stitch them together.

It would be more convenient syntactically to make an extension method out of your Combine method, which would make it available anywhere you go.

Comment: I like the extension method idea, I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if LINQ already had a method that would do the same thing (and be immediately to understandable to other developers further down the line)