# How to concatenate two IEnumerable<T> into a new IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, concatenation

I have two instances of `IEnumerable<T>` (with the same `T`). I want a new instance of `IEnumerable<T>` which is the concatenation of both.

Is there a built-in method in .NET to do that or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: You might want to bookmark http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.

Comment: related, if it helps: [Elegant way to combine multiple collections of elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493858/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-collections-of-elements)

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Yes, LINQ to Objects supports this with [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var together = first.Concat(second);
```

NB: Should `first` or `second` be null you would receive a `ArgumentNullException`.  To avoid this & treat nulls as you would an empty set, use the null coalescing operator like so:

```
var together = (first ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Concat(second ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()); //amending `<string>` to the appropriate type
```

Comment: I always forget looking up extension methods, tx.

Comment: @SamuelRossille Also don't forget that the names of actions you want to perform are likely close if not exactly called what you are after. Always browse IntelliSense, you learn a lot.

Comment: Is it bad to do second = first.Concat(second) ? will we have any concurrency issues?

Comment: @user2934433: Nope, that's absolutely fine.

Comment: Just a quick note. It is required to import `using System.Linq`  namespace at the top of code file to see the desired extension method in the IDE intellisense.

Answer (score 26):

The `Concat` method will return an object which implements `IEnumerable<T>` by returning an object (call it Cat) whose enumerator will attempt to use the two passed-in enumerable items (call them A and B) in sequence.  If the passed-in enumerables represent sequences which will not change during the lifetime of Cat, and which can be read from without side-effects, then Cat may be used directly.  Otherwise, it may be a good idea to call `ToList()` on `Cat` and use the resulting `List<T>` (which will represent a snapshot of the contents of A and B).

Some enumerables take a snapshot when enumeration begins, and will return data from that snapshot if the collection is modified during enumeration.  If B is such an enumerable, then any change to B which occurs before Cat has reached the end of A will show up in Cat's enumeration, but changes which occur after that will not.  Such semantics may likely be confusing; taking a snapshot of Cat can avoid such issues.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a relatively old post, but if you wanted to concatenate multiple IEnumerable's, I use the following

```
var joinedSel = new[] { first, second, third }.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x);
```

This eliminates any null IEnumerable's and allows for multiple concatenations.

Answer (score 10):

You can use below  code for your solution:-

```
public void Linq94() 
{ 
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

    var allNumbers = numbersA.Concat(numbersB); 

    Console.WriteLine("All numbers from both arrays:"); 
    foreach (var n in allNumbers) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(n); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off of **craig1231**'s answer, I've created some extension methods...

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> JoinLists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)
    {
        var joined = new[] { list1, list2 }.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x);
        return joined ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> JoinLists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2, IEnumerable<T> list3)
    {
        var joined = new[] { list1, list2, list3 }.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x);
        return joined ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> JoinMany<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] array)
    {
        var final = array.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x);
        return final ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime C#12 introduced the spread operator "..". You you can apply that on any IEnumerable easily

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerableA = [1,2];
IEnumerable<int> enumerableB = [3,4];
IEnumerable<int> merged = [ ..enumerableA, ..enumerableB ];
```

see: [C#12 Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions)

Answer (score -3):

```
// The answer that I was looking for when searching
public void Answer()
{
    IEnumerable<YourClass> first = this.GetFirstIEnumerableList();
    // Assign to empty list so we can use later
    IEnumerable<YourClass> second = new List<YourClass>();

    if (IwantToUseSecondList)
    {
        second = this.GetSecondIEnumerableList();  
    }
    IEnumerable<SchemapassgruppData> concatedList = first.Concat(second);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of the existing answers.