# how to add list of floats within a list of floats in c#, unity?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a forloop that loops through an array and converts the array into a list of float.

```
    private List<Single> xfloats;

for (int i = 0; i < DataServerManager.instance.x.Count; i++)
{
xfloats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select(str => (ok: Single.TryParse(str, out Single f), f)).Where(t => t.ok).Select(t => t.f).ToList();
}
```

I have another list of floats called 'tempList' and I want to add the results from 'xfloats' into the tempList. But I am getting the error: **error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'float'**

```
      List<float> tempList = new List<float>();
        tempList.Add(xfloats);
```

**How do I add a list of floats into a list of floats?**

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `List<T>.AddRange`.

Comment: or maybe simply `tempList = new List<float>(xfloats);` or also `tempList = xfloats.ToList();` (using `System.Linq`) if it is supposed to only initialize the list once with the given array items ?

Comment: anyway this should answer your question [AddRange to a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474863/addrange-to-a-collection) and [Add multiple items to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345005/add-multiple-items-to-a-list/41508608)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds in the question text like `tempList` will already have some data in it, but in the code samples like it looks like a new empty list. Those two situations call for different answers.

If `tempList` already has data:

```
var xfloats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select(str => (ok: Single.TryParse(str, out Single f), f)).Where(t => t.ok).Select(t => t.f);
tempList.AddRange(xfloats);
```

If it does not already have data:

```
var xfloats = DataServerManager.instance.x.Select(str => (ok: Single.TryParse(str, out Single f), f)).Where(t => t.ok).Select(t => t.f);
var tempList = xfloats.ToList();
```

In both cases, `xfloats` will be an **`IEnumerable<int>`** rather than a List. This will help performance and memory use.

Answer (score 0):

If its a new list then

```
List<float> tempList = new List<float>(xfloats);
```

Or, if you list already exists

```
tempList.AddRange(xfloats);
```