# Merge two objects and remove dupplicated properties for myObject in IEnumerable<myObject> with Linq (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm work with `IEnumerable` of `myObjects`. Those `myObjects` are set by the `App.config` and other XML files.

I load the config in an object-model for each file and then I add the content in `myObjects`. So I want to merge the object-models in only one.

`myObjects` contains `IEnumerable` of `myObjectChild` and `myObjectChild` contains `IEnumerable` of `myObjectChildChild`.

I'm a little bit lost in all these `IEnumerable` and didn't know how to merge this.

Here are the classes:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyObjectChild> MyObjectChilds { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectChild
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyObjectChildChild> MyObjectChildChilds { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectChildChild
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDIT ////

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects)
    {
        List<MyObject> objectConfigList = new List<MyObject>();
        foreach (var myO in myObjects)
        {
            if (objectConfigList.Any(a => a.Name == myO.Name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("myO already in the list: " + myO.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Check current myO.myOC");
                List<MyObjectChild> myOChild = myO.MyObjectChilds.ToList();
                foreach (var myOC in myOChild)
                {
                    if (objectConfigList.Where(a => a.Name == myO.Name).First().MyObjectChilds.Any(s => s.Name == myOC.Name))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("myOC already in the myO: " + myOC.Name);
                        List<MyObjectChildChild> tempmyOCC = myOC.MyObjectChildChilds.ToList();
                        Console.WriteLine("Check current myOC.myOCC");
                        foreach (var myOCC in tempmyOCC)
                        {
                            if (objectConfigList.Where(a => a.Name == myO.Name).First().MyObjectChilds.Where(myOCt => myOCt.Name == myOC.Name).First().MyObjectChildChilds.Any(p => p.Name == myOCC.Name))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("myOCC already defined in this myOCction: " + myOCC.Name);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                objectConfigList.Where(a => a.Name == myO.Name).First().MyObjectChilds.Where(myOCc => myOCc.Name == myOC.Name).First().MyObjectChildChilds.ToList().Add(myOCC);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objectConfigList.Where(a => a.Name == myO.Name).First().MyObjectChilds.ToList().Add(myOC);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                objectConfigList.Add(myO);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found a solution beacause I didn't succeed with the proposed.

I post my solution here, if you have any amelioration to propose, I'll be glad to read it !

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please show some piece of code?

Comment: Use Distinct().

Comment: From the description of a problem we can only guess what's your problem. Read on [ask] and post [mcve] to get any help.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post, I'm a little lost. I've added the classes, I work with IEnumerable<MyObject> and want to merge all MyObject without losing any MyObjectChildChild

Comment: You are trying to join the two sets, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164974/how-to-concatenate-two-ienumerablet-into-a-new-ienumerablet ? If an item can appear in both lists, but shouldn't appear in the resulting output, then you're going to have to use IEquatable then you could union them together.

Comment: Yes, I want to join the sets, I will try your solution, thanks !

Comment: Just a side note: a property of `IEnumerable` with get and set is quite horrible.

Comment: Owh ! I didn't knew that, but I'm not the first to work on this project, I have to add some functionality and I'm not the author of the models. Thanks for the remark, I note that.

Answer (score 0):

To merge many ienumerables of the same type from different ienumerables, you have `.SelectMany()`

Answer (score 0):

To merge two list you can use [IEnumerable.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, but this doen't ensure check duplicates

You can use [IEnumerable.Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove duplicates, but MyObject must implement IEquatable interface

```
public class MyObject : IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyObjectChild> MyObjectChilds { get; set; }
    public bool Equals<MyObject>(MyObject other) { return this.Name.Equals(other.Name);    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to do that :).