# Linq query on arrays of tuples

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

```
(Type, int)[] Format1 = new[] {(typeof(Foo),1)};

(Type, int)[] Format2 = new[] { (typeof(Bar), 1),(typeof(Baz),1) };

IEnumerable<Type> allTypes() => //Foo,Bar,Baz
```

Can you help with:

1. how to temporarily union `Format1` and `Format2` in a quick way, so that...
2. we can extract the types out of the tuples and return them in `allTypes()`

Comment: Merge them into a list and `Select` `Item1`?

Comment: Try using `.Concat`:  `allTypes = Format1.Concat(Format2);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two IEnumerable<T> into a new IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164974/how-to-concatenate-two-ienumerablet-into-a-new-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Type> allTypes() => Format1
    .Select(t => t.Item1)
    .Union(Format2.Select(t => t.Item1));
```

`Union` removes duplicates as desired, otherwise use `Concat`.