# Sort Lists of Objects from Different Classes which Inherit Base class - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, inheritance, base-class

I'm working in VB.net but any examples in .Net or fundamentals would be appreciated.  I have several classes that inherit the same base class.  IN the base class there is a property of type integer.  I would like to sort the several lists of the various classes based on this property from the base class.  I'm familiar with the .Sort using the address of a shared function to sort a list of objects.  The issue I am having is that there are several different lists of different classes and I want to sort them all as one big list.  Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thank you.  David

Comment: just .Concat() them all and .OrderBy(x => x.Property) - that should do (use Concat<TBase>() .Cast if needed to bring them all down to base class)

Comment: have you tried anything yet? please provide some attempts

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  Like NSGaga said, I think putting them into a separate list using .Concat would work, but I'm having trouble Casting the types down to the base class.  I'll look into it further, I appreciate the feedback, I think I'm getting on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it would be suitable to implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) in your base class and then just use the `.Sort()` method on the list containing all of your objects derived from the base class:

```
Class MyClass
    Implements IComparable(Of MyClass)

    Private m_MySortValue As Integer

    #Region "IComparable<MyClass> Members"

    Public Function CompareTo(other As MyClass) As Integer
        If Me.m_MySortValue < other.m_MySortValue Then
            Return -1
        ElseIf Me.m_MySortValue > other.m_MySortValue Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

    #End Region
End Class
```

If you need to put all objects into one big list before sorting you could use [`Concat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493858/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-collections-of-elements) or just create a new list and use [`AddRange`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-addrange) to add all elements from the other lists.

Comment: The OP stated that he/she has multiple lists -- not just one list -- that need to be sorted into a single list.

Comment: @roryap You could just put all objects into the same list for sorting and still use the method above. I can add that to the answer as well.

Comment: Hi floele.  Just to clarify, I have 1 list of each of several class types all inherited from the same base class.  So I have various lists each of a different type.  I think combining them into one list of type base class would be ideal, but am having trouble with the Casting.

Comment: @user3553878: Please further explain what your problems with casting are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of casting derived classes to base class:

Sample classes:

```
Public Class Book
    Inherits Item
    Public Property Author As String = ""
End Class
Public Class Tape
    Inherits Item
    Public Property Artist As String = ""
End Class
Public Class Item
    Public Property Name As String = ""
    Public Property Price As Double = 0.0
    Public Property Quantity As Double = 0.0
    Public Overloads Function ToString() As String
        Return Price.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

Code:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Book)(
{
    New Book With {.Price = 1.0},
    New Book With {.Price = 2.0}
    })

Dim list2 As New List(Of Tape)(
    {
        New Tape With {.Price = 3.0},
        New Tape With {.Price = 0.95}
    })
Dim list3 As List(Of Item) = (From item1 In New List(Of Item)(list1).Concat(list2)
                                Order By item1.Price
                                Select item1).ToList
```

This will return a list of base class from derived classes sorted by a specific property in the base class.  One caveat is the new list is of type base class and won't have any of the specific properties/methods of the derived classes.

Comment: Thank you.  The only difference I needed to make in VB.net (at least for the application I'm working on) is that I could not make a generic list, but rather need to make and IEnumerable using the from statement.  This seems to work so far.  Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to mark this answered to help others that have the problem.  Thanks.