# copy data from one collection to another C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I want to copy data from one collection to another. I'm using following code.

```
foreach (var x in invVM.invFreeItemsWithBatch)
            {
                invVM.invitemsWithBatch.Add(x);
            }
```

But this is wrong. How can I correct?

[image]

[image]

```
public ObservableCollection<InvFreeItemWithBatch> invFreeItemsWithBatch = new ObservableCollection<InvFreeItemWithBatch>();
    public ObservableCollection<InvFreeItemWithBatch> AddInvFreeItemsByBatch(int intitemID, string stritem, double dblqty, double dblamount, string struOM, bool blnfreeIssue,
        double dbluPrice, double dbldiscPerce, double dbldiscAmount, string strbatch, double dblBalanceForFreeqty)
    {
        invFreeItemsWithBatch.Add(new InvFreeItemWithBatch(intitemID, stritem, dblqty, dblamount, struOM, blnfreeIssue, dbluPrice, dbldiscPerce,
            dbldiscAmount, strbatch, dblBalanceForFreeqty));
        stritem = ""; struOM = "";
        return invFreeItemsWithBatch;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<InvItemWithBatch> invitemsWithBatch = new ObservableCollection<InvItemWithBatch>();
    public ObservableCollection<InvItemWithBatch> AddInvItemsByBatch(int intitemID, string stritem, double dblqty, double dblamount, string struOM, bool blnfreeIssue,
        double dbluPrice, double dbldiscPerce, double dbldiscAmount, string strbatch, double dblBalanceForFreeqty)
    {
        invitemsWithBatch.Add(new InvItemWithBatch(intitemID, stritem, dblqty, dblamount, struOM, blnfreeIssue, dbluPrice, dbldiscPerce,
            dbldiscAmount, strbatch, dblBalanceForFreeqty));
        stritem = ""; struOM = "";
        return invitemsWithBatch;
    }
```

Comment: what are invitemsWithBatch and invFreeItemsWithBatch ?

Comment: As ASh said, we need to know what is "wrong" what is the error?  Maybe in the mean time you can look also at this question/answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493858/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-collections-of-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy items from list to list without foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952185/how-do-i-copy-items-from-list-to-list-without-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

*invFreeItemsWithBatch* contains different type of elements than *invitemsWithBatch*.

One list contains the type of *InvItemWithBatch* elements, the other contains *InvFreeItemWithBatch.*

You could create new element in the `foreach` if You like.

```
foreach (var x in invVM.invFreeItemsWithBatch)
{
    var newItem = new InvFreeItemWithBatch();
    // set the values of newItem to match the values of x
    // ...
    invVM.invitemsWithBatch.Add(newItem);
}
```

Also consider making *InvItemWithBatch* the base class of *InvFreeItemWithBatch*:

```
class InvFreeItemWithBatch : InvItemWithBatch
```

that way You can type

```
foreach (var x in invVM.invFreeItemsWithBatch)
        {
            invVM.invitemsWithBatch.Add(x);
        }
```

But You have to consider, that the two list will have the same reference for the `x`.